# (gvim:11507): IBUS-WARNING **: 13:19:44.753: gvim has no capability of surrounding-text feature

Tags: vim

I get these error message.

What is this error message?

It is covering my terminal like this.

(gvim:11507): IBUS-WARNING **: 13:19:44.753: gvim has no capability of surrounding-text feature

(gvim:11507): IBUS-WARNING **: 13:19:44.753: gvim has no capability of surrounding-text feature

(gvim:11507): IBUS-WARNING **: 13:19:44.753: gvim has no capability of surrounding-text feature

(gvim:11507): IBUS-WARNING **: 13:19:44.753: gvim has no capability of surrounding-text feature

(gvim:11507): IBUS-WARNING **: 13:19:44.753: gvim has no capability of surrounding-text feature

How can I handle this?

My .vimrc file is as follows.

```
    syntax on
    set ts=2
    set sw=2    
    set sts=0
    colorscheme slate
    set cindent
    set number "relativenumber
    set ruler
    set gfn=D2Coding\ 12
    set showmatch
    set smartcase
    set fileencoding=utf-8
    set enc=utf-8
    set cursorline 
    hi cursorline guibg=black
    set cursorcolumn
    hi cursorcolumn guibg=black
    "set fen"fold enable
    set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w[%L][%{&ff}]%y[%p%%][%04l,%04v]
    "              | | | | |  |   |      |  |     |    |
    "              | | | | |  |   |      |  |     |    + current column
    "              | | | | |  |   |      |  |     +-- current line
    "              | | | | |  |   |      |  +-- current % into file
    "              | | | | |  |   |      +-- current syntax in square brackets
    "              | | | | |  |   +-- current fileformat
    "              | | | | |  +-- number of lines
    "              | | | | +-- preview flag in square brackets
    "              | | | +-- help flag in square brackets
    "              | | +-- readonly flag in square brackets
    "              | +-- rodified flag in square brackets
    "              +-- full path to file in the buffer
    set ai "auto indent
    set si "smart indent
    set nobackup
    set noswapfile
    set mousef

    " statusline
    " cf the default statusline: %<%f %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%) %P
    " format markers:
    "   %< truncation point
    "   %n buffer number
    "   %f relative path to file
    "   %m modified flag [+] (modified), [-] (unmodifiable) or nothing
    "   %r readonly flag [RO]
    "   %y filetype [ruby]
    "   %= split point for left and right justification
    "   %-35. width specification
    "   %l current line number
    "   %L number of lines in buffer
    "   %c current column number
    "   %V current virtual column number (-n), if different from %c
    "   %P percentage through buffer
    "   %) end of width specification
    set colorcolumn=81
    highlight colorcolumn ctermbg=235 guibg=black
    set sessionoptions-=options
    set autochdir
    filetype plugin on
    filetype indent on
    let g:tex_flavor='latex'
    let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
    let @t = ':tabnew '
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ts setfiletype typescript
    set tabpagemax=100
    set guioptions=m
    "set guioptions=t
    set guitablabel=%M%t
    "set fmr=/*,*/
    "set fdm=marker
    inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<Esc>ko
    set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME
    let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1

    "autocmd Syntax c,cpp,vim,xml,html,xhtml setlocal foldmethod=syntax
    "autocmd Syntax c,cpp,vim,xml,html,xhtml,perl normal zR

    augroup remember_folds
        autocmd!
        autocmd BufWinLeave * mkview
        autocmd BufWinEnter * silent! loadview
    augroup END
```

Comment: A quick googling tells me that many programs seem to have trouble with that specific ibus feature (Gnome terminal, Google Chrome, etc.). Opinions differ about where to submit bugs but if I were you I would open an issue on [Vim's issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues) (hopefully with more details baout your environment) and close this question.